# Numpy: argwhere axis=-1 contains a value >= 0

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional array that have its values split into two groups, either positive (zero inclusive) or negative. My goal is to get all but the final dimension's indices for the positive (zero inclusive). My example should make things clearer.

```
import random
import numpy as np

a = np.full((3,3,2), -1, dtype=np.int32)
for i in range(3):
    x = random.randint(0, 2)
    y = random.randint(0, 2)
    z = random.randint(0, 1)
    a[x][y][z] = random.randint(0, 1)

# example array
#[[[-1, -1],
#  [-1, -1],
#  [-1, -1],],
#
# [[-1, -1],
#  [-1, -1],
#  [ 1, -1],],
#
# [[ 8, -1],
#  [-1, -1],
#  [ 9, -1],]]

# find third dimensions where any value is positive
dimensions = set()
for (x, y, z) in np.argwhere(a >= 0):
    dimensions.add((x, y))

# print dimensions from previous step
for (x, y) in dimensions:
    print a[x][y]

# example output
# [ 1, -1]
# [ 8, -1]
# [ 9, -1]
```

Specifically, I'd like to do something like the following, except that it will work if the final dimension happens to be of all zeroes.

```
for (y, x) in np.argwhere(a.any(axis=-1)):
```

The naive implementation works fine, but I'm sure there's a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
i0, i1, i2 = np.where(a >= 0)

a[i0, i1, :]
```